# How can I automatically pull a repo when a push is made on Centos 8 NodeJS

Tags: node.js, github, centos8

So I am attempting to set up an automated pull/workflow with my current project.

Basically I would like to be able to push changes to my github repo, and from there have the server (Centos 8) pull the repo (if any changes, I'd like to avoid using crontab if possible) and restart the node process.

I tried to use the post-receive hook but that seems to not work and the only other option I have been able to find is to set up a crontab that just pulls the repo every X minutes, but that is not really efficient imo and could cause some server issues.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: quick question: can you not use any ci/cd ? and or incase you using pm2 they have a feature of that kind I believe.

Comment: I can use cd/ci yes, and I would be using pm2.